# sed from pattern till end of file inside a for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

I'm writing a bash script that would allow me to take a certain amount of text from a file and add some other text before that for a list of files.

```
directory=$(pwd)

    for f in *test.txt
    do


        filename=$(basename $f .txt)

        printf "%%sum=4 \n"> input.temp
        printf "file=$directory"/"$filename".txt" \n">> input.temp

        printf "some commands \n">> input.temp

        printf "\n" >> input.temp
        printf "description \n">> input.temp

        sed -n "/0 1/,$p" "$f" >> input.temp;


mv input.temp $filename.temp
done
```

I have a problem with the sed command inside the for loop. I looked around and people suggest adding double quotes which I did but to no avail. I think it might be the $p.
I hope this is clear enough. If it's not, I'll try to explain better.

`sed -n "/0 1/,$p" "$f" >> input.temp;` does not work

`sed -n '/0 1/,$p' "$f" >> input.temp;` does not work

`sed -n "/0 1/,\$p" "$f" >> input.temp;` does not work

FYI I'm not trying to find something else that works. I want to fix this exact input. I sound like an asshole I'm sure.

Sample input

```
%sum=8
file=otherpath/filename.txt
some other commands

another description

0 1

                       0.36920852   -0.56246512    
                       0.77541848    0.05756533    
                       2.05409026    0.62333039    
                       2.92655258    0.56906375    
                       2.52034254   -0.05096652    
                       1.24167014   -0.61673008    
                      -0.60708600   -0.99443872    
                       0.10927459    0.09899803    
                       3.90284624    1.00103940    
                       3.18648588   -0.09239788    
                       0.93151968   -1.09013674    
                       2.50047427    1.30468389    
                       2.19361322    2.54108378   
                       3.18742399    0.34152442   
                       3.38679424    1.11276220   
                       1.56936488    3.27250306    
                       1.81754180    4.19564055    

     1 2 1.5 6
     2 3 1.5 
     3 4 
     4 5 1.5
     5 6 1.5 
     6 11 1.0
     7
     8
     9
     10
     11
     12
     13 16
     14 
     15
     16 17
     17
```

My desired output is basically this file from "0 1" till the end preceded by the stuff I put inside the printf.

UPDATE: If you're interested, the two scripts tripleee and Ed Morton provided work perfectly well. The problem in my script was me leaving out the -i option from the sed line (for inplace).

```
sed -n "/0 1/,$p" "$f" >> input.temp
```

should be replaced by

```
sed -ni '/0 1/,$p' "$f"
```

Comment: I think you want single quotes, to prevent `$p` from being treated as a shell variable rather than sed code: `sed -n '/0 1/,$p' "$f" >> input.temp`. It is somewhat difficult to divine what exactly you're trying to do there, though.

Comment: The braces are just wacky here.

Comment: You are aware that each successive iteration will over-write inputout.temp2, right? I'm guessing this was just a test bed, but FYI

Comment: I fixed the % sign problem. The mv command is supposed to move the temp file into the original file to replace it. sed with simple quotes does not work.

Comment: Yes it does.  Maybe you misunderstood something.  The fix is to use single quotes around the `sed` script only; `sed -n '/0 1/,$p' "$f"` so the file name argument should still be in double quotes.

Comment: To replace the original file, `mv 'input.temp' "$f"` at the end.  Or investigate using `sed -i` if you have that.

Comment: The usual explanation of inexplicable "doesn't work" is that you have DOS line feeds or some other problem with your input which isn't visible to us. Maybe post a new, separate question with more and better details about this specific problem if you really cannot figure it out.

Comment: the thing is when I launch my script as an executable it just freezes (runs indefinitely).

Comment: Probably stuck waiting for input in some unrelated part of the script.  Try the usual debugging techniques -- run with `sh -x` et al.

Comment: running sh -x script shows that it gets stuck on the sed line. It doesn't seem to take the $f however  because it prints `sed -n '/0 1/,$p'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you updated your question and provided some additional information in your comments so try this, uses GNU awk 4.* for `-i inplace`:

```
awk -i inplace -v directory="$(pwd)" '
FNR==1 {
    print "%%sum=4 "
    print "file=" directory "/" FILENAME
    print "some commands "
    print ""
    print "description "
    found = 0
}
/0 1/ { found = 1 }
found
' *text.txt
```

If you don't have GNU awk then the technically correct way to do it is using xargs but it's simpler using a shell loop for the file manipulation (moving) part:

```
for file in *test.txt
do
    awk -v directory="$(pwd)" '
    FNR==1 {
        print "%%sum=4 "
        print "file=" directory "/" FILENAME
        print "some commands "
        print ""
        print "description "
        found = 0
    }
    /0 1/ { found = 1 }
    found
    ' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately the system I'm working on has awk 3.1.7.

Comment: You should upgrade as you're missing a LOT of extremely useful functionality. I added a non-gawk solution to my answer for now though.

Comment: OK, guess your stuck with it then. Some key things to keep in mind - the UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to sequence those calls. The UNIX tool for simple substitutions on individual lines is sed. The UNIX tool for general purpose text manipulation is awk. So, in general when you need to manipulate text in UNIX, you call awk from shell. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have already commented, you basically just need to use single quotes instead of double, because `$p` in double quotes gets replaced with the value of the shell variable `p` by the shell, before `sed` executes (in practice, probably an empty string).

However, you might also want to investigate doing it all in `sed`.  You might then instead stick with the double quotes (because there are other variables you do want to substitute) and instead escape the dollar sign in `$p` with a backslash to protect it from the shell.

```
directory=$(pwd)   # just do this once before the loop; the value doesn't change
for f in *text.txt; do
    # no braces
    filename=$(basename "$f" .txt)
    sed -n "1i\\
%sum=4\\
file=$directory/$filename.txt\\
some commands\\
\\
description
        /0 1/,\$p" "$f" >inputout.temp2  # no pointless separate temp file
done
```

In practice, I imagine you would like for the output file to be different in each iteration (maybe `"$filename.temp"` instead?) but what you do about that is up to you, obviously.  As it is now, the file will contain the output from the last iteration.

Comment: It inserts the desired text on the first line of generated output, instead of fiddling with numerous `printf` invocations.

Comment: Ok. So this works. But, could you please help me understand why my sed doesn't (not with single or with double quotes)

Comment: sed -n '/0 1/,$p' "$f" >> input.temp does not work inside the for loop

Comment: Wit double quotes, the shell expands `$p` to an empty string, so you get a syntax error when `sed` sees `/0 1/,` without an action.  Putting the script in single quotes instead should work, or keep the double quotes and use a backslash like I did in the answer.

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/YZgo6J -- I had to make one small change which I have incorporated in the answer above.

Comment: So I figured it out, I doubt anyone is interested. The problem was leaving out the -i option for sed.